# Error caused by Dropbox in update manager

Tags: update-manager, dropbox

I am getting the following error message when the update manager runs:

> Apt Authentication issue
>
> Problem during package list update.
>   The package list update failed with a
>   authentication failure. This usually
>   happens behind a network proxy server.
>   Please try to click on the "Run this
>   action now" button to correct the
>   problem or update the list manually by
>   running Update Manager and clicking on
>   "Check".
>
> W: A error occurred during the
>   signature verification. The repository
>   is not updated and the previous index
>   files will be used.GPG error:
>   http://linux.dropbox.com lucid
>   Release: The following signatures were
>   invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release
>
> W: Some index files failed to
>   download, they have been ignored, or
>   old ones used instead.

This error started to appear recently and for no obvious reason (maybe because I created myself a private PGP key?). I'm running Dropbox v0.7.11 on Ubuntu Lucid 10.04.

Comment: It is not related to your private key. It is most likely a temporary failure with the Release.gpg file n the server, can you retry the update ?

Comment: This error has been keeping popping up for a few days. Still no fix...

Answer (score 3):

As Joao was explaining it is probably a temporary problem. However as a note for future reference the messages given by the update manager are not always "Informative" in which case It's probably a good idea to do the process in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and check the output for any errors as they can be more informative. In my case I was getting an error recently saying that I didn't have a correct key for a standard update from the main repo so no special ppa's. After doing it in the terminal it showed it has actually having difficulty connecting with the server presumably the first thing that is checked is the key! Anyway to solve the problem I just opened software centre and from the edit menu chose software sources and in the "Download from:" choose other hit the select best button this will ping all the servers to find the best. Obviously it will ignore any that aren't up at the time so you are guaranteed to get your update.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error - [Update Manager Error - Authentication Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15569/update-manager-error-authentication-error)

At least for now it seems to be fixed. I went System > Administration > Software Sources. Once there under the "Ubuntu Software" tab I changed the drop down menu to "Main Server." I than ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

in the terminal. When it finished I clicked close on the Software Sources box and allowed it to update.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like linux.dropbox.com is down; but you can get the gpg key with...

In terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
```

this may fix the Problem