# Update Manager Error - Authentication Error

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

When I run Update Manager I get this error:

[image]

This is what the error box says:

> W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.GPG error: http://linux.dropbox.com lucid Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release
>
> W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Click **System>>Administration>>Software Sources**
- Click the Download From menu and choose **Main Server**
- Type the following in terminal.
  `sudo apt-get update`
- Run the update manager again.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the public key for the Dropbox repository, instructions from https://www.dropbox.com/downloading?os=lnx:

> We have also authenticated our Ubuntu repositories. Please run
>    `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E` to install Dropbox's public key.

Comment: I've done this and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be too worried about that error. It simply means that some files could not be found (probably the keys that are used to "sign" the repository). If you added the keys, then don't worry about it. If you have not added them however, you may need to get them from http://linux.dropbox.com/ and [add](http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) [them](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.ubuntu.com%2Fcommunity%2FSecureApt&ei=uT_1TNrtBcGB8gb74az1BQ&usg=AFQjCNHEwnC_7KoLn0Xty30T2L0ovWquQw&sig2=8NDfmR6JlbKwyon-Drcspw) [to](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CBoQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.ubuntu.com%2Fcommunity%2FRepositories%2FUbuntu&ei=uT_1TNrtBcGB8gb74az1BQ&usg=AFQjCNG4GdiWJnvIRaSjq-b6aOHN0e9eCg&sig2=xqs8-U6qfQGiE4SidoQncg) your system.

Answer (score -2):

In Software Sources
GO to authentication and  restore defaults. Type the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```