# GPG Error, can't update 12.04

Tags: updates, gnupg, signature

I have seen the following question, however it doesn't solve my problem:

- [Update Manager Error - Authentication Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15569/update-manager-error-authentication-error)

I can't update my Ubuntu 12.04! I get the following error after running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
E:GPG error: http://http precise/ Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

Following is the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/linux/distributions/ubuntu/ pr$
deb-src http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/linux/distributions/ubuntu$
3rd Party Binary Repos
#### Google Chrome Browser - http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/
## Run this command: wget -q https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.$
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

#### What I have tried so far:

- I have tried changing sources and made a new, clean `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. But the issue still persists.
- Running `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf` doesn't help either.

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: post the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? Nothing here points to any differences between this and [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15569/update-manager-error-authentication-error), but if none of the solutions there helped, then this should of course be investigated further. Does the error message *actually* say `http://http precise/`? That's not a valid URL. If not, what *does* it say? If so, what's the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` (i.e., the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`), as @bodhi.zazen requested. (You can edit your question to provide large blocks of text.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I don't want to sound silly but I found it was my network connection.  I am at an office where we have tight internet security on on wired LAN.  I have been working on this for 3 days now.  As soon as I switched to our open public wireless, I was able to run the clean and update without any problems.  I hope it's that easy for you as well.

FWIW: I'm running Zorin Linux with 3.5.0-23 kernel on 64bit

Comment: I had the same problem, as I lock down my home Internet by using OPENDNS.  I bypassed it by changing my DNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf