# apt-get update Error

Tags: updates, proxy

I am running into this message whenever I try to do sudo apt-get update...

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg
Get:2 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security Release.gpg
Get:4 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                             
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg         
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                             
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security Release                       
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                    
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release    
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                 
E: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 behind my university proxy. can anyone help?

Comment: If that doesn't help perhaps it's an issue of the GPG error? There's a long thread about it here: [GPG key error when attemting to download updates](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1869890). Note that [I'm not providing this as an answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281/25656) because I have no experience of proxy servers or GPG errors.

Comment: If [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy) (which this is currently closed as a duplicate of) doesn't help, see [Update Manager Error - Authentication Error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15569/update-manager-error-authentication-error), which is about this specific error (with "`NODATA`").