# Signatures error

Tags: 12.10, rails

I am getting the below error when I try to run the command  `sudo apt-get update`:

```
E: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

Search all forums and tried all sorts of possible solution like clean, update, but nothing seems to help. Can anyone help ? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

This will remove GPG error. After you can run your update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Also, you can try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/15574/147044.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this option. But does not work

Comment: Let me just try out the solution in the link . Thanks :)