# Awkward GPG error with Ubuntu Server running "sudo apt-get update"

Tags: 13.04, server, gnupg, signature

I just installed raring 32 bit server on an old machine, it seemed to work fine, but when I try to run `sudo apt-get update` I get this error (I'm translating from Italian)

```
E: GPG Error: http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security
Release: The following signatures were not valid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

This is just awkward, I never experienced something like this, what should I do?
PS: I can't install any package because they are not recognized (i.e. if i try to install `openjdk-6-jdk` it tells me that the package cannot be found)

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: See to be a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/q/15569/236