# Removing faulty links from /var/lib/apt/

Tags: apt, updates

When I use `apt-get`, I get the following error:

```
E: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.cofy.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

I've pasted the link into chrome and it returns error message 503.

First, I tried grepping and rm:ing every single file or directory in `/var/lib/apt/lists` which had the name *spotify* in it, and then `apt-get update`. The problem persists.

Guidance from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err) thread i did `rm -v /var/lib/apt/lists*` and the `apt-get updat`e. This is not a very elegant solution, as it removes everything, right? How much is it safe to remove and then get back again?

However, The problem still persists. The faulty file is obviously somewhere else. Where is it, and how do I get at the bastard?

Comment: Look in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Manager Error - Authentication Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15569/update-manager-error-authentication-error)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jos said you need to find the bad entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

To do it easily without explore all the files and the lines you can make a search with **grep** :

```
grep -nri "repository.spotify.cofy.com" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

**Parameters:**

`-n`  Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.

`-r`  recursive

`-i`  ignore-case