# E: GPG error: http://mega.nz ./ InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Tags: apt, updates, xubuntu

Running Xubuntu 14.04LTS

Originally, I was getting the following error

```
E: GPG error: http://mega.nz ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

Did what [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15569/update-manager-error-authentication-error) told me to do, tried updating again. New problem arose.

```
E: GPG error: http://mega.nz ./ InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Having the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error. Since its a recent issue, i believe it must have been a problem with the megasync server. I fixed it by going to 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d 
and then deleting all the files that started with mega using :

> sudo rm mega*

Then run:

> sudo apt-get update

Comment: While this fixes the immediate problem, wouldn't MegaSync be outdated if this is done? I would rather not have that, if possible.

Comment: Since that seems to be a problem on the mega side, i could only find that as an appropriate solution until they fix it. It's better than not being able to `apt-get update`

Comment: rather than removing mega* files, cp it somewhere outside, now remove the files mega* and then update ubuntu. When needed, cp back mega* files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same error. 
Though the above mentioned technique may work, I'll suggest a more cleaner way

1. Go to **System Settings** -> **Software & Updates** -> **Other
   Software**.
2. Uncheck the option containing `http://mega.nz ./ InRelease`.

This will get your `apt-get update` working without having to remove your configuration settings. 
Lastly wait for Mega to create a patch for this bug and re check the the box again using the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

Megasync GPG issue is fixed by reinstall.(UBUNTU18.04)
Open "software and update",then delete "https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_18.04/" ripository.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove megasync
rm -rf ~/.local/share/data/Mega\ Limited
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

Download megasync-xUbuntu_18.04_amd64.deb from MegaSync

```
sudo dpkg -i megasync-xUbuntu_18.04_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

launch Magasync.